# Why each() does not working with pluck() using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my token table I have two records but I need only `amount` column.

```
$hasToken = $this->hasMany(Token::class, 'user_id', 'id')->pluck('amount')->toArray();
```

Above relation returns two record

> array(    "0" => 500,    "1" => 500, )

I want to plus them by using laravel `each()` or `every()` function but does not working

```
$hasToken->each(function ($item, $key) use($totalTokens) {
    $totalTokens += $item;
});
```

Also I can't try to check count in `if-statement` using below script

```
if($hasToken->count() > 0){ ... }
```

because it is returning error.

Comment: try `collect($hasToken)->each(function ($item, $key) use($totalTokens) {
            $totalTokens += $item;
});`  or `$hasToken = collect($this->hasMany(Token::class, 'user_id', 'id')->pluck('amount')->toArray());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of things wrong here.

First, you should not convert your collection to an Array if you want to perform an [each()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-each) over it. That's a method specific to [Laravel Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections).

```
$hasToken = $this->hasMany(Token::class, 'user_id', 'id')->pluck('amount');
```

Second, you want to modify a value `totalTokens` which I assume is outside your scope.

So, you should pass it by reference. The following should work.

```
$totalTokens = 2; 

$hasToken->each(function ($item, $key) use(&$totalTokens) {
    $totalTokens += $item;
});

dd($totalTokens); // outputs 1002
```

Also `$hasToken->count()` should work again.

Edit: The `&` operator denotes that this variable is being [passed by referenced](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) to the closure.

If you omit the `&`, it means `$totalTokens` is passed by value to the closure. In other terms, it is copied to the closure. Any operations that you will do to the `$totalTokens` will not be known outside its scope.

Comment: What does means of `&` ?

Comment: Edited my answer to explain it a bit better :)